# When I clear data from my Android device, it wipes out the tables that were created in onUpgrade method of my DB helper

Tags: android, sqlite

When using SQlite database in my android app, I have two tables being created in onUpgrade method. On my test device, if I go to settings > apps > myApp > storage and press "Clear data" button, the next time I want to test the app, it crashes and complains that the two tables does not exist. I am fairly new to SQlite world, so any instruction would be appreciated.
Here is part of my DBHelper class:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_MAPS_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if (oldVersion < 2) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_TRACK_RECORD_TABLE);
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_TRACK_POINT_TABLE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Whoever gave me a negative, it would be much nicer if you at least let me know why I deserve it.

Comment: did you change the version of your sqlite database to 2?

Comment: Well if you give clear data it should wipe out your db and cache files related to your app? If you don't want the user to have control over their data its better to implement them on server side.

Comment: @L2_Paver yes, I did increase DB_VERSION to 2.

Answer (score 1):

If you delete the App's data, then the **onUpgrade** step will not run because the **onCreate** method runs, which will set the version to the coded version.

If you need to delete all existing data and change the schema then you code to create the new schenma (tables etc) should be in the **onCreate** method. The **onUpgrade** method is intended for introducing changes to an existing database.

> Thank you very much Mike! I just don't understand the difference.

This is what happens when the database (a file) is opened (i.e. an attempt is made to access the database via an instance of the Database Helper) via a Database Helper (a class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper).

1. A check is made to see if the the database file (ie the database's name is the file name) exists at the given location (typically `data/data/the_package_name/databases/the_database_name`).

   1. the_package_name and the_database_name will differe from app to app.
2. If the database file does not exist then create the file setting the user version (version) in the file's header to the version passed via the Database Helper (other things are done such as creating the sqlite_master table (done by the SQLite API) and adding the android_metadata table that store the locale). The file is now open so **onCreate** is called and a jump is made to step 4.
3. If the file does exist then get the user version stored in the file's header if it is not the same as the version number passed via the Database Helper then

   1. if the version passed via the Database Helper is greater then the version extracted from the file's header then call **onUpgrade** passing the version as per the file's header and the version passed via the Database Helper and a jump is made to step 4.
   2. if the version passsed via the Database Helper is less than the version extracted from the file's header then call **onDowngrade** passing the version as per the file's header and the version passed via the Database Helper and a jump is made to step 4.
4. The database has now been opened so return to the doing the user's request.

As such deleting the App's data takes the path 1 (check if db exists), 2 (create db, setting version and call onCreate) and then 4 (hand control back).

Comment: Thank you very much Mike! I just don't understand the difference. If as you kindly described, onUpgrade doesn't get called after the clear data, then how the changes to an existing database will possibly apply?

Comment: Thanks agin. Your explanation shed light on the issue. So, if I have understood correctly, when I want to make a change to an existing table, I do it in the create statement which is called inside onCreate method for those who are making a fresh installation and do not have the older version. I should also put the same changes in terms of alter statements inside onUpgrade method for those users who already have the app and just want to upgrade to the new version. Is that right?

Comment: @Bahman To make a change to an existing table and keep existing data you would tend to use [ALTER TABLE](https://sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html) (noting that it's quite limited, but also noting that the link covers how to handle other changes which is basically copy the data into a new table drop the original table and rename the new table to the original). If adding a new table then typically you would add the new table into onCreate (using `IF NOT EXISTS` (for **ALL** tables)) on call **onCreate** from **onUpgrade**. The new installs create all the tables and upgrades add the new table.